# I am getting an error in when i am trying to execute django models migrate command - python manage.py migrate . How to solve this error?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User


    class Student(models.Model):
        rollno = models.CharField(max_length=13)
        name = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        dept = models.CharField(max_length=30)

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.name)


    class Subject(models.Model):
        subname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        deptname = models.CharField(max_length=50)

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.subname)
```

> PS C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\django\studentportal> python manage.py migrate
> Operations to perform:
> Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, studentapp
> Running migrations:
> Applying studentapp.0003_auto_20210602_0944...Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Akhil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields_*init*_.py", line 1823, in get_prep_value
> return int(value)
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'CSE'

I tried to delete a model which I have created. After deleting whenever I try to migrate the model, I am getting this error. So I added the same model Subject again

Comment: have you written any view or any data put in model from admin?

Comment: Show the contents of `0003_auto_20210602_0944.py` (In `studentapp/migrations`). It seems you provided a string as a default for an `IntegerField`?

Comment: Yeah! I have deleted those migrations and runner the commands again. And all the errors are gone. Thank you for your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've changed a field in your database to an `IntegerField` and back again? If the database can be wiped, I suggest deleting it, and migrations, and then rerunning `./manage.py makemigrations` and `./manage.py migrate`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have deleted the migrations and all the errors are gone!!

Comment: Can you mark my answer as the right one then pls?